# ValidationError [SequelizeValidationError]: notNull Violation: mapPoints.latitude cannot be null, notNull Violation: mapPoints.longitude cannot be nul

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

i have a little problem. i'm making my backend in nodeJS, i use sequelize for implement database.

here the schema for DB:

[DB Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHNDw.png)

my problem is in the mapPoint table and game table.

here is my server :

game.model.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Game = sequelize.define("games", {
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      latitude: {
        type: Sequelize.FLOAT,
        allowNull: false
      },
      longitude: {
        type: Sequelize.FLOAT,
        allowNull: false
      }
    });
    
    
    return Game;
  };
```

mapPoint.model.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const MapPoint = sequelize.define("mapPoints", {
      latitude: {
        type: Sequelize.FLOAT,
        allowNull: false
      },
      longitude: {
        type: Sequelize.FLOAT,
        allowNull: false
      }
    });
    return MapPoint
  };
```

my create function

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    // Save User to Database
    Game.create({
      name: req.body.name,
      latitude: req.body.latitude,
      longitude: req.body.longitude,
      userId: req.body.userId
    }) 
    .then((mapPoints) => {
        console.log("------------- in .then")
        if (req.body.mapPoints) {
            console.log("------------- in if")
            MapPoint.create( 
                console.log("------------- in create"),
                {
                latitude: req.body.latitude,
                longitude: req.body.longitude
            })
            .then(() => {
                console.log('xxxxx: ' + mapPoints);
                game.addMapPoints(mapPoints)
                .then(() => {
                    res.send({message: "MapPoint was added successfully"})
                })
            })
        }
    });
  };
```

and relation 1:N between the game table and mapPoint table

```
// mapPoint -> game

db.game.hasMany(db.mapPoint, { as: "mapPoints"});
db.mapPoint.belongsTo(db.game, {
    foreignKey: "gameId",
    as: "game"
});
```

when i post json on postman, he send me error

postman: [postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5AkY.jpg)

the error:

```
/Users/arktik92/Desktop/CatServer/node_modules/sequelize/lib/instance-validator.js:50
      throw new sequelizeError.ValidationError(null, this.errors);
            ^

ValidationError [SequelizeValidationError]: notNull Violation: mapPoints.latitude cannot be null,
notNull Violation: mapPoints.longitude cannot be null
    at InstanceValidator._validate (/Users/arktik92/Desktop/CatServer/node_modules/sequelize/lib/instance-validator.js:50:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async InstanceValidator._validateAndRunHooks (/Users/arktik92/Desktop/CatServer/node_modules/sequelize/lib/instance-validator.js:60:7)
    at async InstanceValidator.validate (/Users/arktik92/Desktop/CatServer/node_modules/sequelize/lib/instance-validator.js:54:12)
    at async model.save (/Users/arktik92/Desktop/CatServer/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:2368:7)
    at async Function.create (/Users/arktik92/Desktop/CatServer/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1344:12) {
  errors: [
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'mapPoints.latitude cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'latitude',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: mapPoints {
        dataValues: {
          id: null,
          updatedAt: 2022-12-01T11:30:06.247Z,
          createdAt: 2022-12-01T11:30:06.247Z
        },
        _previousDataValues: {},
        uniqno: 1,
        _changed: Set(0) {},
        _options: {
          isNewRecord: true,
          _schema: null,
          _schemaDelimiter: '',
          attributes: undefined,
          include: undefined,
          raw: undefined,
          silent: undefined
        },
        isNewRecord: true
      },
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    },
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'mapPoints.longitude cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'longitude',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: mapPoints {
        dataValues: {
          id: null,
          updatedAt: 2022-12-01T11:30:06.247Z,
          createdAt: 2022-12-01T11:30:06.247Z
        },
        _previousDataValues: {},
        uniqno: 1,
        _changed: Set(0) {},
        _options: {
          isNewRecord: true,
          _schema: null,
          _schemaDelimiter: '',
          attributes: undefined,
          include: undefined,
          raw: undefined,
          silent: undefined
        },
        isNewRecord: true
      },
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    }
  ]
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

can you help me please ?

Comment: `mapPoints` is actually the `Game` instance

Comment: and you don't use the result of `MapPoint.create`